# Solr 8.0.0 Delta import add/delete data

Tags: solr

We have a MySql database (news) which has the following fields - posting_id, date, name, currency, country, expiry ....etc

The database has more than 1200000 entries. Daily around 200000 plus new records are added and around the same number deleted.

posting_id is a unique ID for every record.

Please can some help write a delta-import script so that the index file is update as per the records in the MySql database (news) everyday. If the posting_id is not found in the database (news) then the same is deleted from the solr indexed file and the records with new posting_id are indexed.

The following doesn't work

````
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            batchSize="-1"
            autoReconnect="true"
            socketTimeout="0"
            connectTimeout="0"
            url="jdbc:mysql://xxxx/livenews?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
            user="admin"
            password="admin"/>
<document>
  <entity name="news"  
    pk="id"
    query="select * from news"
    deltaImportQuery="SELECT * from news WHERE id='${dih.delta.id}'"
    deltaQuery="SELECT id FROM news WHERE updated_at > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
    >
     <field column="posting_id" name="posting_id"/>
     <field column="date" name="date"/>
     <field column="name" name="name"/>
     <field column="currency" name="currency"/>
     <field column="country" name="country"/>
     <field column="expiry" name="expiry"/>

  </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>```
````

Comment: Can you post your logs? For the deletion of rows you will need to have a new table where all deleted ids will resent. You can achieve this by using a trigger or something. Then you need to have the select query of that table in another attribute 'deletedPkQuery'.

Comment: Very new to Solr. Does solr have any syncing script. Solr automatically checks the MySql database and indexes it according to the changes in the main database. <br> 

```
WARN false SimplePropertiesWriter Unable to read: dataimport.properties

ERROR false EntityProcessorBase getNext() failed for query 'select * from news':org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

Comment: For full index: use the query attribute, for incremental index: use deltaImportQuery/deltaQuery with the last_index_time field. This does look good on your snippet. For deletion, you have to feed solr with id's (the pk="id") of rows that were deleted. Therefor you will need to store them in a separate table. You can fill this table through your application code but to me using a trigger seems easier. 

For the log error: check if the file dataimport.properties exists in your solr/Module/conf folder. This file holds the last-index variables. Also check read/write permissions

Comment: So no syncing script exists as far as i know. Also to schedule incremental (delta) indexation, you will have to write some sort of tool that calls a url (through curl for example) to trigger indexation. But for the rest, solr is really a fantastic search server tool, just lacks some basic stuff like indexation scheduling and it has a strange way to feed it. Once you get used to it, you are going to love it :-)

Comment: Thanks. created the dataimport.properties file. Still having issues regarding indexing of all the records. <br>
Have already opened a ticket to this reference with the errors at - [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55645825/solr8-0-0-not-all-records-getting-indexed[/link]

Answer (score 0):

So to wrap it together.

Make sure you have the file dataimport.properties in your [SolrPath]/server/solr/[CoreName]/conf folder and check the read/write permissions. If the file does not exist i think it is safe to just create it.

This file will contain the last index timestamps per entity for example:

```
>     #Fri Apr 12 07:12:02 UTC 2019 
>     Conversations.last_index_time=2019-04-12 07\:11\:40
>     ContentSites.last_index_time=2019-04-12 07\:11\:40
>     last_index_time=2019-04-12 07\:11\:31
>     Messages.last_index_time=2019-04-12 07\:11\:59
>     LibraryItems.last_index_time=2019-04-12 07\:11\:41
>     CalendarItems.last_index_time=2019-04-12 07\:11\:31
```

You query/deltaImportQuery/deltaQuery are looking quite ok. For deletion you miss the deletionPkQuery attribute which should get the id's of the deleted items. Therefor it is needed to have a new table per entity which holds the ids of deleted items. You can fill it with application code or you can set triggers on your content/item-tables to fill the deletion table automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Created the dataimport.properties file in /var/solr/data/newscore/conf
Still not indexing the full data.

DataImporter
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Comment: Can you try to making the conf directory writeable for everyone?