# Solr8.0.0 not all records getting indexed

Tags: solr

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            batchSize="-1"
            autoReconnect="true"
            socketTimeout="0"
            connectTimeout="0"
            url="jdbc:mysql://xxxx/livenews?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
            user="admin"
            password="admin"/>
<document>
<document>
<entity name="news"
    query="select * from news">
     <field column="posting_id" name="posting_id"/>
     <field column="date" name="date"/>
     <field column="name" name="name"/>
     <field column="currency" name="currency"/>
     <field column="country" name="country"/>
     <field column="expiry" name="expiry"/>

  </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

While doing full import getting the following message -
Last Update: 11:31:09
Requests: 1 , Fetched: 951,104 , Skipped: 0 , Processed: 951,104  
Started: 4 minutes ago

However the overview shows
Last Modified: 2 minutes ago 
Num Docs: 941601
Max Doc: 941601

Not all records are getting indexed. Logging shows the following message -

```
WARN false SimplePropertiesWriter Unable to read: dataimport.properties

ERROR false EntityProcessorBase getNext() failed for query 'select * from news':org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

ERROR false DocBuilder Exception while processing: news document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

ERROR false DataImporter Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

ERROR false CommitTracker auto commit error...:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
```

If I change the batchSize to 1000, solr stops working. Have to restart solr again.
Tried with both of these -
mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar

Comment: What is the uniqueKey field? Do you have possible duplicate ids in your result set? (later documents will override the previous versions in those cases)

Comment: posting_id has unique numbers